# POST GWT CORS request works but PUT CORS request doesn't

Tags: http, gwt, cors

I'm writing a GWT frontend for a personal project, and I'm having problems with some HTTP requests. When I do a CORS POST request, it works fine

```
String url = BASE_URL + "students/";

RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, url);
builder.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.onelostlogician.student+json");
builder.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
StringBuilder basicAuth = new StringBuilder();
basicAuth.append(username.getValue());
basicAuth.append(":");
basicAuth.append(password.getValue());
String basicAuthStr = basicAuth.toString();
builder.setHeader("Lambda-Authorization", "Basic " + toBase64(basicAuthStr.getBytes()));
StudentWriter studentWriter = GWT.create(StudentWriter.class);

try {
    builder.sendRequest(studentWriter.write(student), new RequestCallback() {
        public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
            addItemDialog.close();
            responseDialog.open();
            loadingIcon.setVisible(false);
            responseHeading.setText("No response");
            responseLabel.setText(request.toString());
        }

        public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
            loadingIcon.setVisible(false);
            String responseText = response.getText();

            List<Map.Entry<Integer, Student>> students = model.getList();
            Integer studentId = Integer.parseInt(responseText);

            students.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(studentId, student));
            model.setList(students);

            // clear text fields
            className.setValue("");
            additionLevel.setValue("");
            additionProblems.setValue("");
            subtractionLevel.setValue("");
            subtractionProblems.setValue("");
            multiplicationLevel.setValue("");
            multiplicationProblems.setValue("");
            divisionLevel.setValue("");
            divisionProblems.setValue("");

            addItemDialog.close();
        }
    });

} catch (RequestException _) {
    // Code omitted for clarity
}
```

The options request gets a 200 response (chrome network inspection below):

```
General
Request URL:https://[redacted].execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/students/
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 
Remote Address:54.230.9.41:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers
access-control-allow-headers:content-type, lambda-authorization
access-control-allow-methods:post, get, put
access-control-allow-origin:*
content-length:0
content-type:application/json
date:Wed, 13 Sep 2017 14:56:32 GMT
status:200
via:1.1 5db82aafd9021b07695423274288b59e.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id:8nJ2gzqHFPiiDOOeEelzkpI7Ga9SFdEcljiLt2pvm7Z995_GicxPVw==
x-amzn-requestid:bb0e23db-9893-11e7-bbbe-9bea7d9d70bf
x-amzn-trace-id:sampled=0;root=1-59b94720-d892209d8c5c2a04832bdb85
x-cache:Miss from cloudfront

Request Headers
:authority:[redacted].execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
:method:OPTIONS
:path:/v1/students/
:scheme:https
accept:*/*
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
access-control-request-headers:content-type,lambda-authorization
access-control-request-method:POST
origin:http://127.0.0.1:8888
referer:http://127.0.0.1:8888/ArithmeticExerciseGeneratorClient.html
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36
```

and then the POST request occurs as expected

```
General
Request URL:https://[redacted].execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/students/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:201 
Remote Address:54.230.9.41:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers
access-control-allow-origin:*
content-length:1
content-type:application/json
date:Wed, 13 Sep 2017 14:56:33 GMT
status:201
via:1.1 5db82aafd9021b07695423274288b59e.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id:gxYrwctM75ObiPyS4nD69jXSO4dBaMAOZmXXX0mPE4wMgCdcjUSQsA==
x-amzn-requestid:bb381a33-9893-11e7-a1f1-17fd67ca388c
x-amzn-trace-id:sampled=0;root=1-59b94720-1c1e3a8d8c9ce2741c789241
x-cache:Miss from cloudfront

Request Headers
:authority:[redacted].execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
:method:POST
:path:/v1/students/
:scheme:https
accept:application/json
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
content-length:224
content-type:application/vnd.onelostlogician.student+json
lambda-authorization:Basic [redacted]
origin:http://127.0.0.1:8888
referer:http://127.0.0.1:8888/ArithmeticExerciseGeneratorClient.html
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36

Request Payload
{"className":"6T","additionProblemId":4,"additionNoOfProblems":5,"subtractionProblemId":3,"subtractionNoOfProblems":5,"multiplicationProblemId":2,"multiplicationNoOfProblems":5,"divisionProblemId":1,"divisionNoOfProblems":5}
```

Unfortunately, a PUT request to a very similar resource, on the same server, doesn't. The code is almost identical:

```
String url = BASE_URL + "students/" + studentId;

RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.PUT, url);
builder.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.onelostlogician.student+json");
builder.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
StringBuilder basicAuth = new StringBuilder();
basicAuth.append(username.getValue());
basicAuth.append(":");
basicAuth.append(password.getValue());
String basicAuthStr = basicAuth.toString();
builder.setHeader("Lambda-Authorization", "Basic " + toBase64(basicAuthStr.getBytes()));
StudentWriter studentWriter = GWT.create(StudentWriter.class);

try {
    builder.sendRequest(studentWriter.write(student), new RequestCallback() {
        public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
            addItemDialog.close();
            responseDialog.open();
            loadingIcon.setVisible(false);
            responseHeading.setText("No response");
            responseLabel.setText(request.toString());
        }

        public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
            loadingIcon.setVisible(false);
            responseDialog.open();
            loadingIcon.setVisible(false);
            responseHeading.setText("Response: " + response.getStatusCode());
            responseLabel.setText(response.getText());
        }
    });

} catch (RequestException _) {
    // Code omitted for clarity
}
```

The options request gets a 200 response:

```
General
Request URL:https://[redacted].execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/students/4
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 
Remote Address:54.230.9.41:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers
access-control-allow-headers:content-type, lambda-authorization
access-control-allow-methods:get, put
access-control-allow-origin:*
content-length:0
content-type:application/json
date:Wed, 13 Sep 2017 14:58:38 GMT
status:200
via:1.1 5db82aafd9021b07695423274288b59e.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id:0PoyOa6oDBSmU7iCWZyeSZFqWxZvumN8C4GtHn8rsoJK5AURbj3kxQ==
x-amzn-requestid:063270d4-9894-11e7-9d66-71b07b2689ef
x-amzn-trace-id:sampled=0;root=1-59b9479e-39be94b25784b92027fa2753
x-cache:Miss from cloudfront

Request Headers
:authority:[redacted].execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
:method:OPTIONS
:path:/v1/students/4
:scheme:https
accept:*/*
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
access-control-request-headers:content-type,lambda-authorization
access-control-request-method:PUT
origin:http://127.0.0.1:8888
referer:http://127.0.0.1:8888/ArithmeticExerciseGeneratorClient.html
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36
```

…but after receiving a successful `OPTIONS` response, it does not make the `PUT` request at all.

In the Chrome console I get:

> XMLHTTPRequest cannot load https://[redacted]/v1/students/5. Method
>   PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight
>   response

I don't understand that error, given that we can see "`put`" in the `access-control-allow-methods` response header for the preflight `OPTIONS` request shown above.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In the part of the question where you say, *“doesn't then go on to perform the required PUT CORS operation”*, please consider using https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46202370/edit to edit/update the question to clarify exactly what you mean there? You probably want to open the Network pane in your browser devtools and reload and look and then go back and in your question, indicate (1) Does the browser really not send the PUT request at all after that OPTIONS? Or does it? and (2) If it does, what response status code (2xx, 4xx, 5xx?) & headers does the server send in response to that PUT request?

Comment: Edited for clarification. The browser does not send the PUT request at all after that OPTIONS.

Comment: And the browser engine does not log any error message of any kind? Sorry for not being familiar with how GWT troubleshooting works, but is there no  console where errors get logged? If there is, no errors logged there? And are you able to test some version of the code in a different browser? Firefox? (To see if you get the same no-PUT-request-sent behavior.)

Comment: The problem exists in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox (which are the browsers I have access to). In the Chrome console I get "XMLHTTPRequest cannot load https://[redacted]/v1/students/5. Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response". I don't understand that error, given that we can see "put" in the "access-control-allow-methods" above.

Answer (score 0):

In the POST response, the allowed methods header is

```
access-control-allow-methods:post, get, put
```

In the PUT response, the allowed methods header is

```
access-control-allow-methods:get, put
```

Note that the required method is the first in the list of the POST case, but second in the list in the PUT case. When I modified the server to put the method under consideration first in the list (and, also, to make it case sensitive, because HTTP method names are case sensitive), the browser then performed the required followup PUT request.